# Is there a full XMPP client, for any mobile? [that sends/receives files, etc., like PC clients do]

Tags: xmpp

I've got a few friends to install XMPP clients on their cell phones. Some installed Xabber (which I basically chose for them to try). Another opted for Yaxim, a few days ago (for its "better appearance") after - for an unrelated problem - resetting his device totally and losing many things, including the installed programs, which included Xabber.

But there seems to be too many limitations that I did not expect for these clients, compared with everything I do, using a computer, with anyone else in most XMPP clients.

I can't send files to them while we're chatting, as I would do normally if they were using any XMPP client on a PC. And it seems that xabber does not have it all (and not much documentation either, so I could check); Yaxim neither.

whatsapp is bad because it only works with a phone number - which I surely don't want or need to give for most people, but its popularity is unquestionable, so I'm barely alone with that idea within some groups of people.

Is there a XMPP client that would support all things (or, at least, most) that people expect from a mobile client? Easily sending pictures or other "things" that mobiles usually have accessible within other programs, but without limiting it to a specific protocol. And all things that we can do with XMPP on a computer, like: sending/receiving files/pictures/whatever; personalized emoticons; sound messages; VOIP (although I never tried it with XMPP).

I even imagine it using any open and free cloud file service to easily send a big file (like a video) to several users without waiting more than ~1 time for uploading or downloading this file (downloading to see and, resend to others after that).

Yaxim seems freezed since 2013. That seems too long ago for anyone else?!

Xabber seems better, but still limited. It is mentioned as "the best", in some software review sites I have read.

Are there any better clients for XMPP? Which features does it have, and what is bad about it? Does anyone else miss this?

Comment: You may want to check the ["xmpp" tag](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xmpp) on [softwarerecs.se] (and/or ask your question there).

Comment: [ answered Sep 10 at 12:17] Basically the same question, but still no much info or answers:

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/showthread.php?p=5414726#post5414726

Comment: Basically the same question, but [...] p=5414726
 deleted by jasonwryan, Michael Mrozek♦ 2 days ago 
Why post deleted? [...] Sep 10 at 12:17 

[Balaco] This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post. –  jasonwryan 2 days ago    => You could have copy/pasted it into a comment, instead of deleting an information I think it's useful, although not directly an answer.